# How to show Eclipse Notification Options Settings

Tags: eclipse, settings

How do I see the past notification in Eclipse where I choose "Do not show this message again"?

I turned off the settings of missing line number error because it is annoying for a time so I can focus in fixing a bug. But now, I want it shown again so I can research on the line number problem.

Comment: What 'missing line number' error is this? What programming language?

Comment: All more details about error. Also you may find this option in `Windows > Preferences` to re enable